# React callback ref not expose class methods from outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

The task is: implement React component for toasts - hiding by itself, showing from outside.
Most of React guides describe how to access DOM from React component.
Almost nothing about how to access React component from DOM.
My code for React component is:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Alert extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.type = null;
        this.message = null;
        this.state = { show: false };
        this.alertCallbackRef = alert => { window.toast = alert; };
    }

    show = (type, message) => {
        this.type = type;
        this.message = message;
        this.setState({ show: true });
    }

    hide = () => {
        this.setState({ show: false });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div ref={this.alertCallbackRef}> // here ref
                    {
                        this.state.show ? (
                            // here visible part
                        ) : null
                    }
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Then check `<Alert/>` tag on HTML page:

- window.toast contains DOM Node <div></div>.
- window.toast.any_function (show / hide / etc) - is not a function.

What's wrong?

Comment: The ref is pointing to the `div`, not to the component.  `window.toast = this` should work in the constructor

Comment: @Konrad: great! I'm so silly - ref don't return class instance, just some DOM nodes

Answer (score 1):

1. Cancel all about refs in code
2. Just assign `window.toast = this` in constructor. Thanks to @Konrad